# Linux PC randomly halts [instant power off] and doesn't power back on power switch unless AC power is cut

Tags: power-supply, acpi, halts, cpufreq

my Linux pc is randomly powering off. the working configuration:

- ATI drivers (fglrx) not loaded
- cpufreq governor (either performance or powersave) and frequency are set at boot (default settings compiled into kernel).
- no suspend-to-RAM (pm-suspend) happened.

Switching cpufreq governor to 'performance' leads to shutoff in ~hour. CPU temperature is normal all the way.

There is a small chance of PSU bugs, but the performance configuration doesn't tends to shutdown often. It seems that a motherboard GA-890GPA-UD3H has a bug in ACPI/somewhere else (wrong AMD Turbo switch?), that is triggered by some PM/cpufreq call to evolve, live and block the whole system unless the AC cable is cut for 5 seconds. It also may be due to PSU, however.

Comment: Replaced the hardware. Problem solved. Even forgot to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it happen in any other OS? I think that would be the decider on whether it's hardware or software.